# How to process several arrays in one range for?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I want to copy an array using `range for`. Is it possible?

Something like (obviously not working)

```
unsigned arr[15] = {};
unsigned arr2[15];

for (auto i : arr, auto &j : arr2)
    j = i;
```

Or are there some other tricks to avoid operating the size of arrays, if I know for sure they are of the same lenght?

**UPD**
I really like the @PavelDavydov solution. But could anyone please offer **a standard lib only solution**. C++11 contains pairs and tuples too.

```
for (auto pair : std::make_tuple(&arr, &arr2));
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the 'classic' `for` loop?

Comment: Because I should know the size.

Comment: You can `std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::begin(arr2)`. Not a for loop, but the size is not used.

Comment: @user2198121 But you know, that `sizoef(arr)/sizeof(*arr)` give you `size` of array?

Comment: Stupid question (mine not yours): What is the type of the arrays? Is `unsigned` by itself a valid type?

Comment: @DuncanACoulter, `unsigned` implies `int` (quite strongly in fact).

Comment: @Tacet, this is a [tag:c++11] question, using `sizeof` is so passé

Comment: @JonathanWakely `int arr[15]` is so passé, we have [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)! Maybe you have right, and `std::distance(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr))` looks better, however, in C++11 we still should use std::array. `arr.size()` looks nobly.

Comment: @Tacet, agreed about `std::array`. I prefer `std::end(a) - std::begin(a)`, it's an array so you know you have RandomAccessIterators

Comment: @TemplateRex, I'm requesting for a standard lib (C++11) solution.

Comment: @user2198121 there is no such solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>

for (const auto& pair : boost::combine(arr, arr2)) {
  cout << get<0>(pair) << endl;
}
```

Update: ok, if you want to do it without boost, you can implement a higher order function for that.

```
template <class T, unsigned long FirstLen, unsigned long SecondLen, class Pred> 
typename std::enable_if<FirstLen == SecondLen, void>::type loop_two(T (&first)[FirstLen], T (&second)[SecondLen], Pred pred) {
  for (unsigned long len = 0; len < FirstLen; ++len) {
    pred(first[len], second[len]);  
  }
}
```

and than use it like this:

```
loop_two(arr, arr1, [] (unsigned a, unsigned b) {
  cout << a << endl;
});
```

Comment: Is it possible with standard lib? C++11 includes pairs. I tried by myself but no luck.

Comment: Can you please give a link to the documentation of `boost::combine`?

Comment: @RalphTandetzky, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/range/combine.hpp

Comment: @user2198121 I did not mean a link to the header file and implementation, but a link to documentation, which tells me, what the thing is supposed to do, preconditions, postconditions, effects, etc.

Comment: @user2198121 I named a variable 'pair' here, but in fact it's a tuples::cons. c++11 doesn't have any similar functions, AFAIK, unfortunately. Be careful however, combine produce undefined behavior if ranges are not equal.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky boost::combine is an undocumented feature.

Comment: @PavelDavydov, but C++11 has tuples too. Or C++11 tuples strongly != Boost tuples?

Comment: If `boost::combine` is not documented, can we rely on it then? There's no guarantee that future boost releases try to maintain the current behavior. That gives me a bad gut feel about this solution. :S

Comment: @RalphTandetzky the documentation will soon be fixed - see https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8028

Comment: @PavelDavydov, thanks! It's a pity, there is no solution for `range for` though.

Comment: @user2198121 yeah, it would be nice if someone add this feature to c++17... Another option we have is just to switch to [d language](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#zip). :)

Comment: @PavelDavydov, yeah, tovarisch! C++17 will be a Revolution! Lenin, Partiya, Digital October!

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iterator>
//.. 

unsigned arr[15] = {};
unsigned arr2[15];

//.. 

auto it = std::begin( arr2 );

for ( unsigned x : arr ) *it++ = x;
```

It would be better to use standard algorithm `std::copy` because its name says about your intention.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
//...

std::copy( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ), std::begin( arr2 ) );
```

For arrays of arithmetic types you can use also C function `memcpy`

```
#include <cstring>

...

std::memcpy( arr2, arr, std::extent<decltype(arr)>::value * sizeof( unsigned ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several good answers already, another is to use a zip iterator such as https://gitlab.com/redistd/redistd/blob/master/include/redi/zip.h (which currently depends on Boost.Tuple)

```
#include <redi/zip.h>

int main()
{
  unsigned arr[15] = {};
  unsigned arr2[15];

  for (auto i : redi::zip(arr, arr2))
    i.get<1>() = i.get<0>();
}
```

Comment: `boost::combine` is such a thin wrapper around a tuple of `zip_iterator`

Comment: @TemplateRex, yes, but it doesn't handle rvalue ranges correctly, you get dangling references (not important here, but in general)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. I suggest use [std::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) function. For example:

```
for(auto it1 = std::begin(arr), it2 = std::begin(arr2); it1 != std::end(arr); ++it1,++it2)
 *it2 = *it1;
```

However, you can use [std:array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead 'normal' arrays. It's C++11!

Comment: N.B. that should be `std::begin` and `std::end`